# Is it possible to include an HTML flat-file website inside a WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development, html, include

Is it possible to include an entire flat-file HTML site (.html, folders/ and CSS) inside WordPress?

Essentially, I want to host an HTML site, but have access to WP functions and plugins. Not to interested in a iframe solution as that would break the look of the URLs on the browser address bar.

Can I include the html site in WP? Or perhaps include WP in the HTML (with some PHP .htaccess extension magic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need site to be processed as PHP, since WP simply won't work otherwise. I think you can do it for non-.php extensions by tinkering with server config.

THen see [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) in Codex. You can load WP core to required degree and use the functions.

However I'd consider just migrating site to WP completely.

Comment: Will simply grabbing the header in a standard PHP page as your link suggests load WP plugins?

Comment: Answered my own question by allowing themes with `define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);`.

Comment: Scratch that, turning themes to true doesn't really help plugins load. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

If I had a site where I wanted to do this I'd convert the layout to a wordpress theme, and then import the pages -- playing with the URL format so that they'd correspond.

Creating a basic theme from existing HTML is pretty easy - see this tutorial for instruction:

http://www.codeislove.net/2011/03/converting-html-layout-into-wordpress.html

http://www.codeislove.net/2011/06/tutorial-converting-html-layout-into.html

You can leave out stuff you're not planning to support - for instance, you might not need the comments, gravatar, sidebars or posts if all you need is full-width pages.

If you can't replicate your URL structure perfectly with the normal WP custom permalinks options, consider redirecting with a plugin, like this one:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-title-url/

(I found this in the plugin directory, and haven't tried it or reviewed it closely.  Evaluate carefully before using. )  A better option, if you can, would be to 301 redirect the old URLs to the corresponding compatible URL.  You can use your .htaccess file, or a WP redirection plugin.